# Authentication Issue User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is False despite successful login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm facing an authentication issue in my ASP.NET Core MVC application using Identity and cookies. Despite a successful login using _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is returning false. I have reviewed my code and setup, but I'm unable to identify the root cause.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(SignInCommand model)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, false);
    //return result;
    // Access the current user's information
    if(result.Succeeded)
    {
      var isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
      var currentUser = HttpContext.User;
      var userId = currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
      var userName = currentUser.Identity?.Name;
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View("Login", model);

  }
```

My Program.cs https://gist.github.com/otmanik/4e41b7c6bef023d6d0081026e10eedf1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be solved the add AddAuthentication before AddIdentity:
I moved builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => ..
before
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>();

Answer (score 0):

At that specific point in time a value of `false` is correct as your `User` is not authenticated (albeit they are authenticating). They are/were not authenticated at the time of accessing the `Login` method.

Try another endpoint (method) that requires a `User` to be authenticated and check the value from there. Assuming a successful authentication the value of

```
var isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

Should be `true`.